# Question about for loop

Tags: procedural-programming

How can I get the results of a "for" loop for each iteration? For example, I have the following for loop and would like to know how I can get the value of S1 for each i value in the output. Also, I am just wondering is there any way to show the name of the variable in the output (e.g: S1 = {{1,2},{2,3}}) and not just {{1,2},{2,3}}?

Thank you and regards,

````
For [i=1,10,++

   For [j=1,20,++

      S1=?

       ]
]```
````

Comment: You can print it in the loop: `Print["S1=" <> ToString@S1];`

Comment: This question has already been posed for hundreds of times and it was virtually always `Table` what the OP wanted (95% of questions that contain "loop" in its title). (`result = Table[<<bla>>,{i,1,10},{j,1,10}]`). (This post could be an exception, though...).

Answer (score 2):

As recommend in comments, better to use Table or Do.

> how I can get the value of S1 for each i value in the output.

For `For` you can still use `Sow` and `Reap` as well

```
result = First@Last@Reap@For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
     For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
      Sow[{i, j}]
      ]
     ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> to show the name of the variable in the output (e.g: S1 =
>   {{1,2},{2,3}}) and not just {{1,2},{2,3}}?

What do you mean by show `S1={...}`? In Mathematica `x=1` is assignment, and Mathematica displays back `1`, not `x=1`. To show `x=1` you would need to force things into strings. Something like

```
 ("S = " <> ToString[#]) & /@ result
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> an example with Table application

```
result = First@Last@Reap@Do[
     Do[
      Sow[{i, j}]
      ,
      {j, 1, 3}
      ],
     {i, 1, 3}
     ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or to make it do something more interesting

```
result = First@Last@Reap@Do[
      Do[
       Sow[{ Row[{"S[", i, ",", j, "]=", i + j}], i + j}]
       ,
       {j, 1, 3}
       ],
      {i, 1, 3}
      ];
```

And now the actual computation result is stored in `result[[All,2]]` and the display part is stored separately  in `result[[All,1]]`

```
result[[All, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
result[[All, 1]] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, Nasser, Can you please provide me an example with Table application.

Comment: @MehdiEbadi fyi, added `Table` example